# Python Encoding person names

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I'm loading data into a postgresdwh encoded at utf-8 which includes personal information - including first name, last name and addresses. These values can have German characters such as `umlauts` as well as French characters such as `é, â, à` etc. Data is being read from Excel files, into a dataframe and then pushed into the postgresql database.
I've previously used the following line to circumvent an encoding error. So for instance on first name values:

```
df = pd.read_excel(dir_path, encoding='utf-8-sig')

df['fname'] = df['fname'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('windows-1252'))
```

I've now encountered French characters which have raised another error:

```
DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe9 0x20 0x20
```

I've changed the encoding to:

```
df['fname'] = df['fname'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8-sig'))
```

However leaving the script as is will not load values with German characters.
I thought `windows-1252` is used for Wester-European languages and should be able to process all these special characters.
Is there an alternative encoding that will apply for all these languages? Or do I need to change the encoding based on the value processed?

Comment: Please edit your Question to show the **corresponding** code line to **DataError('**. Read, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example][1] and edit your Question accordingly.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't show where the DataError comes from, one thing is clear: an "invalid byte sequence" problem is definitely connected to a location where data are *decoded*, not *encoded*.

Thus, if the two lines you show are everything that relates to encoding, then the exception occurs in the first one (`pd.read_excel`).
You cannot receive a problem related to invalid byte sequences when you *encode*, as in the second line (in the lambda expression).

Apparently that specific input is *not* encoded in UTF-8 (with or without BOM).
Confirm:

```
>>> b'\xe9\x20\x20'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

However, based on the information given (French and German characters, the sequence `b'\xe9\x20\x20'`, Windows), good guesses for the actual encoding are CP-1252 or Latin-9 (ISO 8859-15). In both of them, the result is the same:

```
>>> b'\xe9\x20\x20'.decode('cp1252')
'é  '
>>> b'\xe9\x20\x20'.decode('latin9')
'é  '
```

So, try this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(dir_path, encoding='windows-1252')
```

If it doesn't work for all input, you'll probably have to parametrise the encoding and set it accordingly for each input file.